# Mongoose count query with mutliple fields ORed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find a count of all documents with a title or desc field that contains my search string.  I have tried the following and it always just returns all rows, ignoring the filter.

```
FCSet.count([{ 'title': { $regex: re }}, { 'desc': { $regex: re }}]).exec(function(err, count) {
}
```

I can do them one at a time, if I include just title it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FCSet.count( 
    {
        $or: [
            { 'title': { $regex: re } }, 
            { 'desc': { $regex: re } } 
        ]
    }
).exec( function( err, count ) {}
```